# Laravel redirect with variable

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to use redirect with data in Laravel8. But this code is not showing data. What is the problem in syntax ?

**IN CONTROLLER**

```
$list = BE_MEDICAL_INSURANCE_FOR_FOREIGNERS::get();
redirect()->route('dashboard')->with( ['list' => $list] );
```

Comment: the code isn't showing what data? what are you expecting to be "showing"? ... this is just flashing data to the session

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

`redirect()->route('dashboard')->with('list', $list);`

for more info follow https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redirects

Answer (score 0):

First be sure that list load some data with dd($list);
After use redirect helper like

```
$list = //...;
return redirect()->route('dashboard', ['list'=>$list]);
```

you can use closure function in the route in web.php and inspect if the data is bind through the route like

```
Route::get('/dashboard/{list}', function($list){
   dd('list');
})->name('dashboard');
```